# Imagemagick issues with Ruby

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, rvm

I'm trying to run a ruby script from the command line, and getting the following error:

/Users/.../.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require': dlopen(/Users/.../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@stitching_cron/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/lib/RMagick2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libMagickCore.6.dylib (LoadError)

I've installed ImageMagick using

```
brew install imagemagick
```

and the command line utilities are available as expected. Not sure what's happening here.

I tried running

```
sudo find / -type f -name "libMagickCore.6.dylib"
```

to see if I can perhaps symlink the file into the location Ruby is looking for the library, but couldn't find it...

Any idea how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
rvm get head
rvm pkg remove
rvm reinstall 1.9.2-p320 --with-opt-dir=$(brew --prefix imagemagick)
```